# How can I define an implementation of Go interface method that receives pointer?

Tags: pointers, go, interface

The following program runs fine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person interface {
    Hello()
}

type Joker struct {
    Name string
}

func (j Joker) Hello() {
    fmt.Println(j.Name, "says, \"Hello!\"")
}

func main() {
    var j Joker = Joker{"Peter"}
    invokeHello(j)
}

func invokeHello(p Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

Here is the output.

```
$ go run foo.go
Peter says, "Hello!"
```

But when I change the `Hello` method to receive a pointer, I get errors.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person interface {
    Hello()
}

type Joker struct {
    Name string
}

func (j *Joker) Hello() {
    fmt.Println(j.Name, "says, \"Hello!\"")
}

func main() {
    var j *Joker = &Joker{"Peter"}
    invokeHello(j)
}

func invokeHello(p *Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

Here are the errors.

```
$ go run bar.go
# command-line-arguments
./bar.go:21: cannot use j (type *Joker) as type *Person in argument to invokeHello:
    *Person is pointer to interface, not interface
./bar.go:25: p.Hello undefined (type *Person has no field or method Hello)
```

How can I fix the second program?

Answer (score 3):

```
func invokeHello(p *Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

`p` is type `*Person`,  `*Joker` implement interface `Person`, revert `invokeHello` to:

```
func invokeHello(p Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

this will fix the second program.

I think you have misleading about [golang interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to implement the interface.

Comment: To add to this, You pretty much never want a pointer to an interface type. It already is a pointer underneath.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix

You can't use pointers to `interface` type.
That is the problem:

```
func invokeHello(p *Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

Should be:

```
func invokeHello(p Person) {
    p.Hello()
}
```

#### Interface implementation

Types implement interfaces. If type has methods appropriate to a methods declared in an interface than the interface is implemented by the type.

> Interfaces in Go provide a way to specify the behavior of an object: if something can do this, then it can be used here.

#### Types vs pointers to a types

`Type` and `*Type` are different types. For example `*Type` could implement an interface but `Type` can not implement it. But `*InterfaceType` really has no sence to use.

If you want to receive pointer to a type in a function which expects an interface type, implement the interface with pointer receiver, like you did in a second example.

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/4ON3aS2zHq):

```
type Person interface {
    Hello()
}

type Joker struct {
    Name string
}

/*
A Hello method declared with a pointer receiver which means that a pointer to
the Joker type (*Joker) not Joker type itself implements Person interface.
*/
func (j *Joker) Hello() {
    fmt.Println(j.Name, "says, \"Hello!\"")
}

/*
invokeHello receives ANY type which statisfies Person interface.
In this case this is pointer to Joker type.
*/
func invokeHello(p Person) {
    p.Hello()
}

func main() {
    i := Joker{"Peter"}
    j := &i
    // Note difference between types
    fmt.Printf(
        "Joker type: %s\nPointer to Joker type: %s\n",
        reflect.TypeOf(i), reflect.TypeOf(j))
    invokeHello(j)
}
```

Otherwise if you want to receive a value of a type, implement the interface with value receiver, like you did in a first example.

Comment: *"If you want to receive pointer to a type in a function which expects an interface type, implement the interface with pointer receiver, like you did in a second example."* -- Can you add some code that demonstrates this point? I thought this is what I tried but clearly my second example does not work. Can you show some working code where I can receive a pointer to a type in a function that expects an interface type?

Comment: @LoneLearner, yep sure. Keep an eye on the post. I'll update it in a half of an hour.

Comment: @LoneLearner, sorry for delay. Here is your snippet with comments and types printing. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: @LoneLearner , invokeHello receives interface type but not pointer to the interface.

Comment: I am still confused. Your code example seems to be same as my first example (in my question). In my first example, `invokeHello` receives interface type (not a pointer).

Comment: @LoneLearner, in your first example the (j Joker) Hello has value receiver, but in my example (j *Joker) Hello has pointer receiver. That is the difference.